# Post condition Ant style pattern for matching a branch name Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I know that we cannot use **when** conditon in post steps for jenkinsfile but I want to know is there a way where I can use something IF conditon something like if(env.BRANCH_NAME != 'PR**')

```
    success{
        script{
            if(env.BRANCH_NAME != 'PR**'){
                TriggerRemoteJenkins()
            }
        }
    }
```

should match all PR's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it we can use the match opertaor groovy `==~`

```
 if(!(env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /^PR.*/)){
                    TriggerRemoteJenkins()
            }
```

[Match opertaor Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_match_operator)